# C# InvalidCastException when returning single value from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, exception

I am trying to return a value from a SQL database. However everytime I execute the following method I get an error stating, "InvalidCastException was unhandled. Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Any light you could shed on this would be greatly appreciated. The method I am using is as follows.

Thanks.

```
    public static int ScrapTotal2(string prdTypeV, string startDateV, string prtCodeV)
    {
        int scrapTotal2;

        SqlParameter prdType = new SqlParameter("@prdType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        prdType.Value = prdTypeV;
        SqlParameter startDate = new SqlParameter("@startDate", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        startDate.Value = startDateV;
        SqlParameter prtCode = new SqlParameter("@prtCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        prtCode.Value = prtCodeV;

        SqlCommand scrapTotal2SC = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM([QTY_SCRP]) FROM [TBL_PRDMST] WHERE [PRD_CODE] LIKE @prdType AND [PRD_DATE] = @startDate AND [PRT_CODE] LIKE @prtCode", DataAccess.myConnection);
        scrapTotal2SC.Parameters.Add(prdType);
        scrapTotal2SC.Parameters.Add(startDate);
        scrapTotal2SC.Parameters.Add(prtCode);

        DataAccess.myConnection.Open();
        scrapTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(scrapTotal2SC.ExecuteScalar());
        DataAccess.myConnection.Close();

        return scrapTotal2;
    }
```

Comment: does your select return NULL or a valid value? Check in the DB first

Comment: Do you have access to code and able to debug it? It'd be great if you could tell us which line is throwing an exception. Wrap your method code in try-catch and you will get useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SELECT statement returns NULL value. You have to check if it is null first:

```
object result = scrapTotal2SC.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == DBNull.Value) 
{ 
    /* write your code */ 
}
else
{
    scrapTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assumed incorrectly the sum would have been 0 and not null. This worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify, I'm going to assume that this line is the problem:

```
scrapTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(scrapTotal2SC.ExecuteScalar());
```

When you get a NULL in a database, it will be cast to a type of DBNull in your code. This type cannot be cast to an `Int32`.

You can check for it like this:

```
var obj = scrapTotal2SC.ExecuteScalar()
if (obj == DBNull.Value)
{
    // whatever logic you want to handle nulls
} else {
    scrapTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to state which line threw the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error message is clear - your query returns `null` (which in .NET would be a `DbNull`).

This can't be converted to an `Int32`, as integers are value types and cannot be `null`.

Either check the return value for `DbNull` and return a default value from your data layer, or check your query and database to ensure that a `null` will not be returned.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - But it doesn't convert `DbNull` to `0`. `DbNull != null`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yes, it converts `null` to 0, but not `DbNull`.

Comment: @Oded , you right.  When it returns Dbnull its not null in the eyes of .net..... but this statement looks funny : if (sdf==DbNull.Value) finalResult=null.... and then run convert.....funny isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL server think that sum of empty list is null and not 0. So you have to handle the conversion from null to int yourself. Not convert directly the result of the query to int.

Answer (score 0):

try `scrapTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(((string)scrapTotal2SC.ExecuteScalar()));`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because the return value is `NULL` and that you are trying to store in a `INT` type variable ... which can't be done.

Probably what you can do is ...

```
if(retval is null) then assign var = 0.
```

Comment: DBNull is not the same as null, OP has to check if retval == DBNull.Value

Comment: actually, I mean the same but was not able to collect the syntax and hence written in psudeo code.